# A template with variable number of types

Tags: c++, stl, templates, visual-c++

I want to write a C++ template like this:

```
template <class Type1, class Type2, class Type3,....>

    class MyClass
    {
    //...
    };
```

But, "the number of types" is variable.

For example, a user can create an object with 3 types:

```
MyClass<int, int, int> obj;
```

or he can create an object with 5 types:

```
MyClass<int, int, int, int, int> obj;
```

In other words, I want the user :
1.Indicate the number of fields.
2.Set the types according to the number of fields.

how could I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could have a look at Boost.MPL: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html, particularly at `boost::mpl::vector`.

Comment: Out of interest, how are you going to name the fields ?

Comment: I haven't thought of that, this might be a proglem, but I think the answers might have their ways to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should take a look at Alexandrescu's book [Modern C++ Design](http://erdani.org/book/main.html). Chapter 3 on typelists seems to be pretty near to what you want.

Answer (score 7):

[Variadic templates. C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Variadic_templates) :(

Just to mention that you can get around that in current C++. For example, you can take a look at `Boost::tuple`:

```
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::tuple<int, double> tuple1(4, 2.0);
    boost::tuple<int, double, double> tuple2(16, 4.0, 2.0);
}
```

You can't assign a *variable* number of types to the tuple, `boost::tuple` allows you up to 10 types only. I think [litb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/litb) showed how to do that in a previous answer but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works with a compiler implementing (this part of) C++1x. (Which ones do this, BTW?)

Comment: @sbi do you mean the tuple ? it is in boost, it doesn't need Variadic templates to work that way.

Comment: @AraK: Dang, this was a brainfart. It referred to the "variadic templates" at the top of your posting, not to the rest. Sorry for the confusion. It was late last night.

Comment: GCC 4 supports variadic templates :)

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know the only solution right now is to write a separate template for each case. in some cases you might be able to use an enum to type map or a type list, but we would need to know more about what you want to do with the types first.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is your write that template so that it takes a big enough number of arguments, but give default ones to all of them. Then you use template-meta programming to sift through the arguments and weed out the default ones.

Take Neils advice and buy MC++D. That's how most of us learned this technique.